# How can I created a curved health bar?

Tags: actionscript-3, line, equation

I'm making a game with a health bar and I am trying to make a health bar that is curved.

Currently I have a lineBar that has 20 segments that looks like this at the bottom left of the screen.

What I'd like to do is write a function that goes through and modifies the scaleY of each to get a curved bar.

I can easily scale them down in a straight line. So that it looks triangle ish.

I want exponential decay.

In normal math terms it might be something like `y = Pa^x`.

Comment: Cool! And what is your specific programming question?

Comment: Could you [play one of my flash games here](https://projectavian.com/games/daz3/) and tell me if this is the style of health bar you're trying to create?

Comment: Not really an answer but it seems to me, in the interest of saving effort while achieving a nice aesthetic effect, it might be easier to just use partial images. You can show X% of the "full health" from the left and Y% of the empty health image from the right, or any number of variations on that approach..

Answer (score 4):

I developed a game with a curved health bar a while back, this is how I achieved it:

**Step 1:**

Create your curved bar. I suggest the `Oval Primitive` tool:

[image]

Draw your bar. I suggest creating a guide layer to demonstrate a whole-circle visual of your curved segment. Copy the bar onto another layer and make it a mask, this will be what reveals your healthbar. The mask and the segment should be `MovieClips`:

[image]

---

**Step 2:**

Set the registration point of your mask to the centre of your guide circle. Your mask will rotate around this point to reveal your actual bar. Rotate your mask so that it is to the left of your actual bar graphic:

[image]

---

**Step 3:**

Create a tween of your mask rotating clockwise across 100 frames (add more frames for finer progression). You can even apply a tween to your bar graphics where the colour changes from red to green as it fills, etc.

[image]

---

**Step 4:**

Use `gotoAndStop()` on this element to determine which frame you should stop on throughout the animation. The formula I use here is generally:

```
gotoAndStop( Math.round( currentHealth / maxHealth * x ) );
```

Where `x` is the amount of frames you created.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks i may use this some time. I ended up using line segments. First i made a base linebar that you can pass the art of 1 segment, # of segments and spacing for the segments. And i gave it a function for curving using this equation to get a decent curve.